# How to iterate over dates in Python/Mysql? 'datetime.date' is not iterable"

Tags: python, mysql, flask-sqlalchemy

Given a Mysql table with columns ("Title", "Author", "Date"). How do you:

1. Iterate over database to compare a given user provided date input to the database column "Date"
2. append matching records to lists

without getting the error "TypeError: argument of type 'datetime.date' is not iterable" example code below: Python 3.7

```
date = request.form.get("date")
list1=[]
list2=[]
list3=[]
results = db.session.query(Books).all()
for i in results:
     if date in i.date is True:
          list1.append(i.title)
          list2.append(i.author)
          list3.append(i.date)


---------------------------------------------------------------------------

    TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)

<ipython-input-28-c4085a31faa3> in <module>()
      5 results = db.session.query(Books).all()
      6 for i in results:
----> 7      if date in i.date:
      8             list1.append(i.title)
      9             list2.append(i.author)

TypeError: argument of type 'datetime.date' is not iterable
```

Comment: Please, post full traceback message.

Comment: Added full traceback message

Comment: Though I've provided a solution in a different direction, the problem with this code is that `i` is the iterator over the `results` rows over the list. So `i` represents a table row. So `i.date` is a value, not an array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [sqlachemy filter](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/sqlalchemy/sqlalchemy_orm_filter_operators.htm) to search. Doing database operations in application code is comparatively poor performance.

```
results = db.session.query(Books).filter(Books.date==date)
```

Comment: This worked great. I had to change "date=date" to "date==date" otherwise I got the error "SyntaxError: keyword can't be an expression". I am not sure what you mean by poor performance due to a complete lack of knowledge but I will take this working mvp and try to do what I can to improve on it. Thanks  a bunch!

Comment: syntax corrected. Databases are designed around quick searching and joining of data. When you need this functionality you should be looking for the mechanism in sqlalchemy that supports this. It would be ideal if your `Books` definition included an index on `date` to support this query. This allows the database to fetch that row quickly rather than returning a data and requiring you to implement the search (less efficient than databases that have had lots of people improving their performance for a long time).

Comment: Thats great! I will implement that. Thank you for the tip!